# How to find view id in appwidgetprovider?

Tags: android, view, android-appwidget

I have a appwidget extends from appwidgetprovider.

I have created a layout xml file named main_layout.xml and add a button. If i develop a listActivity i reach this button with this path: R.layout.main_layout.button01.

```
(Button)findViewById(R.layout.main_layout.button01)
```

Activity class has a member method that named findViewById() but appwidgetprovider has not.

How can i reach my button in my layout?

sorry for my english

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can never reference or modify views in Appwidget directly. You should do this in [RemoteViews](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RemoteViews.html).

Comment: With my very basic knowledge this sounds - well - pretty stupid and overcomplicated. Could you explain what the thought process is behind handling them differently?