# Read android:src in ImageView in the Widget.xml file

Tags: android, image, widget

I have a Widget that toggles between two images, the widget changes each time a user clicks on it
So I define a layout for this widget as follows

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/parrotstate"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:src="@drawable/widget_awake" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

In the AppWidgetProvide `class`, I need to read the attribute android:src to know which image is set.
Normally I use `findViewById` in the Activity class but here it is AppWidgetProvide `class`

Comment: probably this question is duplicated try with this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4666687/how-to-find-view-id-in-appwidgetprovider

Comment: I know I should use RemoteViews but it does not have a function to access the imageView

Comment: why dont get the count with a boolean? is not difficult the implementation. I will post you an example if you want.

Comment: This boolean maybe killed if declared inside onReceive() of the AppWidgetProvider(). Where should I define it to be saved all the time and read it when clicking on the Widget

Answer (score 0):

probably this question is duplicated try with this post: [How to find view id in appwidgetprovider?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4666687/how-to-find-view-id-in-appwidgetprovider)

With the constructor you can get the Remoteview:

```
RemoteViews(String packageName, int layoutId)
//Create a new RemoteViews object that will display the views contained in the specified layout file.
```

apply returns the view

```
apply(Context context, ViewGroup parent)
//Inflates the view hierarchy represented by this object and applies all of the actions.
```

link: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RemoteViews.html

Comment: I do not understand what is ViewGroup in my case. I have an ImageView inside a RelativeLayout.

Comment: ViewGroup is where do you want to set your View, example a Layout.