# Xamarin Android Widget: How to change Height of ImageView programmatical?

Tags: xamarin.android, android-widget

I have a widget.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/widget"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:focusable="true"
style="@style/WidgetBackground">
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/myimage"
    android:layout_width="20dip"
    android:layout_height="20dip"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:src="@drawable/myimage" />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/mytext"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"       
    style="@style/WidgetText.Title" />
```

How can I change the size of the image?

```
[Service]
public class UpdateService : Service
{
    public override StartCommandResult OnStartCommand(Intent intent, StartCommandFlags flags, int startId)
    {
        var updateViews = new RemoteViews(context.PackageName, Resource.Layout.widget);
        // changing textsize works perfectly:
        updateViews.SetTextViewTextSize(Resource.Id.mytext, (int)ComplexUnitType.Sp, 14);
        updateViews.SetViewVisibility(Resource.Id.myimage, ViewStates.Gone);
        updateViews.SetTextViewText(Resource.Id.text, "new text");

        // but changing imagesize does not work, I didn't find a right way to set the size, need something like this:
        updateViews.SetInt(Resource.Id.myimage, "layout_width ???", 200dip ???);

            ComponentName thisWidget = new ComponentName(this, Java.Lang.Class.FromType(typeof(Widget)).Name);
            AppWidgetManager manager = AppWidgetManager.GetInstance(this);
            manager.UpdateAppWidget(thisWidget, updateViews);


    }
```

updateViews has several setInt, setFloat, Set.. but I didn't find the right method. Any hint please?

Comment: Can you update your full xml and clarify what updateViews is exactly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's impossible to change the height or width of the `ImageView` in code, but there is some workaround.

You could try to create a new widget layout that the size of your `ImageView` is what you want. When you call `RemoteViews()` use it instead of the original one. And when you update the widget, it will be redrawn.
For example:

```
    public override StartCommandResult OnStartCommand(Intent intent, StartCommandFlags flags, int startId)
    {
        //var updateViews = new RemoteViews(this.PackageName, Resource.Layout.widget);
        //Using another layout instead.
        var updateViews = new RemoteViews(this.PackageName, Resource.Layout.layout1);

        ComponentName thisWidget = new ComponentName(this, Java.Lang.Class.FromType(typeof(MyWidget)).Name);
        AppWidgetManager manager = AppWidgetManager.GetInstance(this);
        manager.UpdateAppWidget(thisWidget, updateViews);
        ///...
        ///...

    }
```

Or you could also try to add many`ImageView` of different size in your layout and set the `Visibility` to `Gone`. Show the one you want to display in the code by calling `SetViewVisibility()`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this method:

```
var videoContainer = FindViewById<RelativeLayout>(Resource.Id.local_video_container);
var parameters = videoContainer.LayoutParameters;
parameters.Height = (int)TypedValue.ApplyDimension(ComplexUnitType.Dip, containerHeight, Resources.DisplayMetrics);
parameters.Width = (int)TypedValue.ApplyDimension(ComplexUnitType.Dip, containerWidth, Resources.DisplayMetrics);
videoContainer.LayoutParameters = parameters;
```

Comment: Thanks, but FindViewById seems to be unavailable in widget-context.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4666687/how-to-find-view-id-in-appwidgetprovider