# String array to show text at textview on refresh

Tags: android, arrays, string, textview

Instead of `Text`, it's necessary to read the `R.id.text` text from TextView = My Text, I tried a lot but failed, how, please help.

This is the line:

```
public class MyWidgetProvider extends AppWidgetProvider {
// String array to show text at textview on refresh
private static final String[] refreshStrings = {"Text"};

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:text="My Text"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:textSize="18sp" />
```

I want it to be like this:

`private static final String[] refreshStrings = R.id.text;`

Answer (score 0):

I found this [How to find view id in appwidgetprovider?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4666687/how-to-find-view-id-in-appwidgetprovider), so it is not possible to **reference** or **modify** in `Appwidget` **directly**. One solution could be to use `AppCompatActivity`. Here you can see how to update and modify with `AppCompatActivity` http://android4beginners.com/2013/06/lesson-1-3-how-to-modify-textview-in-java-code-findviewbyid-settext-and-gettext-methods/.

This is my code with `AppCompatActivity` how to get the **text** from the `TextView` by the `R.id.<idname>`

**MainActivity:**

```
package com.example.myapplication;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);
        }
    }
```

**activity_main.xml** (Don't forget to change the standard Layout, I chose LinearLayout):

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:text="My Text"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:textSize="18sp" />
```

Comment: i tried this way but it not work that, thanks for trying.

Comment: Could you post the rest of your code, so it is easier to help you.

Comment: Please look my post

Comment: did that help you ?

Comment: No, sorry, that's not what I'm looking for

Comment: The problem is, that what you wanna do is not possible to do in that way you wanna do it.

Comment: hello? are you here